# Understanding Content in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, supremum-and-infimum, rational-numbers

[image]

[image]

On Page 2 of Baby Rudin contain proof of $\sqrt {2}$ is not rational Number .I understand that .But Below that above content is written.How to obtain that relation between p and q I don't understand .Please Help me .

Comment: What's the question? Why he chooses $q$ like that? Or how to get from (3) to (4)?

Comment: Actually how to obtain that relation ? I do not wanted to memorize above.If you tell any concrete way to obtain above that would be helpful for me.